# Eigenvalues of a matrix with no calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have this matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 && 2 && 3 && 4 \\
2 && 4 && 6 && 8 \\
3 && 6 && 9 && 12 \\
4 && 8 && 12 && 16
\end{bmatrix}

I am supposed to find its eigenvalues without actually calculating them. I can see that in every row the difference between two elements is constant, but I am not sure if this can help me in any way. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hint: How many Linearly Independent rows (or columns) have you got, and can this tell you something about what some of the eigenvalues are?

Comment: Can you see why zero has to be an eigenvalue?

Comment: @StubbornAtom no, I don't really understand why. Can you please explain?

Comment: @ivana14 As the 2nd,3rd and 4th row vectors are linearly dependent on the 1st row, the determinant is zero. As determinant is the product of eigenvalues, at least one of the eigenvalues has to be zero.

Comment: @StubbornAtom ah yes, I see it. Is there a way to determine the multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue? Is it equal to the rank of the matrix?

Comment: That looks rank $1$ to me.

Comment: The multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue is the *nullity*, not the rank.

Comment: Rank equals the number of non-zero eigenvalues.

Comment: @StubbornAtom is it the number of non-zero eigenvalues counting also their multiplicities? thanks

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Rank is equal to non zero eigenvalues only when algebraic multiplicity and geometric multiplicity of Zero eigenvalue are the same.

Comment: @DharmarajDeka ... as it is in this case. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3, and \lambda_4,$ be the eigwn values of the matrix. Clearly the matrix has determinant zero and trace 30.

So, $$\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\lambda_4=30,$$
$$\lambda_1*\lambda_2*\lambda_3*\lambda_4=0.$$

So one of the eigenvalues must be zero. The last thing we need to check is the geometric multiplicity of zero, which will be given by the relation, $$rank=n-geometric/multiplicity/of(0).$$

Rank of the given matrix is 1 and dimension (n) is 4. So geometric multiplicity of eigenvalue zero is 3. Which gives the required eigenvalues as $30,0,0,0.$

Answer (score 2):

It follow from your remark that the matrix has rank $1$. Therefore, $0$ is an eigenvalue and there can be only another eigenvalue.

Now, simply notice that the product of your matrix by the vector $(1,2,3,4)$ is $(30,60,90,120)$.

Comment: only one *non-zero* eigenvalue to be precise.